# Execute R code from readline() function

Tags: r, command-line-interface, user-input

I would like the user to be able to input code and have it executed. I can think of a pretty inefficient solution:

```
code <- readline("Enter code > ")
write(code, "code.R")
source("code.R")
```

Is there a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `textConnection`, here is a demo:

```
code <- readline("Enter code > ")
Enter code > df <- data.frame(x = 1:3)

source(textConnection(code))

df
  x
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

Or use `eval(parse(text = code))`:

```
eval(parse(text = code))

df
  x
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

Comment: Plus one on the eval-parse method